# How to left align the label in a button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I get a material UI button to left align the label? There are no props to directly change the inline-styles on the button element and the only way I can figure to do this is to add a class and write some gross css selector like thisClass > div > button.

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/raised-button

Comment: I tried all the above without any luck. After digging for a bit, I found another related question that has a [very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56812652/positioning-material-ui-label-to-the-left-with-left-alignment) that does in fact work.

Answer (score 34):

I had a similar issue with buttons that have an icon. I fixed it by justifing the content:

```
<Button 
  startIcon={<AccountCircleIcon/>}
  fullWidth={true}
  style={{justifyContent: "flex-start"}}>
  button text
</Button>
```

Comment: It works for me But should set `display: flex` before using `justifyContent`.

Answer (score 3):

You can give the label `absolute` positioning by using the `labelStyle` property on the element. 
This works:

```
 <RaisedButton 
  label="Primary" 
  primary={true} 
  lableStyle={{position: 'absolute',top: 0,left: -10}} />
```

Edit: Updating my answer with better ways to do this

Using text align on the button:

```
  <RaisedButton 
   style={{textAlign: 'left'}}
   label="Primary" 
   primary={true}/>
```

Using float on the label:

```
  <RaisedButton 
   lableStyle={{float: 'left'}}
   label="Primary" 
   primary={true}/>
```

Comment: Works, but feels like a hack to absolute position something that can be done with simple text-align. I think the library just has a hole in it here.

Comment: Yes, the 1rst solution looks like a hack, while the 3rd it is an old one. The second solution is the best, and is semantic: `style={{textAlign: 'left'}}`. I tryed using inyected classes for `text` and `label` ... and yes it works

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<Button
  sx={{ 
    textAlign: 'left',
  }}
>
  button text
</Button>
```