# Positioning material-ui label to the left with left alignment

Tags: material-ui

I'm using the radio button components available from material-ui.com and have set `labelPlacement="start"`. This has placed the label on the left side, but I would also like the labels to be left aligned while leaving the radio buttons on the right.

```
<RadioGroup
    name="switching"
    value="switching"
    onChange={this.handleEstablishingChange.bind(this)}
>
    <FormControlLabel value="switching" control={<Radio />} labelPlacement="start" label={this.props.lang().justswitching} />
    <hr />
    <FormControlLabel value="new_source" control={<Radio />} labelPlacement="start" label={this.props.lang().newsource} />
</RadioGroup>
```

[image]

Comment: Some code demonstrating the issue would be nice.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the code. I hope you will consider removing any downvotes as this is a serious well-specified question. Thanks!

Comment: How are you styling your material components? Are you using JSS as suggested by Material-UI's own docs? Component CSS overrides? I see absolutely no styling attempt in your code, only the use of component props.
Please remember that in order to help you, fellow SO users need to be able to reproduce your issue, and frankly I'm surprised someone with your experience would need to be reminded that.

Comment: I'm also disputing the notion that your question is well-specified. You say you want the labels to be left-aligned, but do you need the radio buttons to remain right-aligned? Do you want the whole label+radio groups to be aligned left, center or right? Or do you want the labels all the way to the left and the radio buttons all the way to the right?

Comment: I need the labels to be left aligned and the radio buttons to be right aligned. I.e. the labels all the way to the left and the radio buttons all the way to the right. I've tried tons of different things. I'm not sure it's useful for me to include all of the things that didn't work. I will accept any working solution whether it's JSS, CSS, or any other implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. See below for my proposed answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple & straightforward solution to your problem using CSS override on the `FormControlLabel` component (which encapsulates both the label and the actual control).

We use Material-UI's `makeStyles` helper to define the class we'll use to override the default styling of `FormControlLabel`. We specifically want to target the `root` key (the full list of available CSS override keys for `FormControlLabel` is available [here](https://material-ui.com/api/form-control-label/#css)), hence we name our class `root` to benefit from destructuring and assignment simplification.

We assign the `classes` object returned from the `useStyles` hook call to the `classes` prop of each `FormControlLabel`. The long-form of that assignment would be `classes={{ root: classes.root }}` but because we named our class `root` (which is the name of the key we're targeting) we can simply write `classes={classes}`.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { RadioGroup, FormControlLabel, Radio } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    // component default is "inline-flex", using "flex" makes the
    // label + control group use the entire width of the parent element
    display: "flex",
    // component default is "flex-start", using "space-between" pushes
    // both flexed content to the right and left edges of the flexbox
    // Note: the content is aligned to the right by default because
    // the 'labelPlacement="start"' component prop changes the flexbox
    // direction to "row-reverse"
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
});

const App = () => {
  const [source, setSource] = useState("switching");
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <RadioGroup
        name="source"
        value={source}
        onChange={e => setSource(e.target.value)}
      >
        <FormControlLabel
          value="switching"
          control={<Radio />}
          labelPlacement="start"
          label={"Switching"}
          classes={classes}
        />
        <hr />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="new_source"
          control={<Radio />}
          labelPlacement="start"
          label={"New Service"}
          classes={classes}
        />
      </RadioGroup>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Working codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-lichterman-lyfx5)

#### Update: additional content about hooks

Say you have the following code (**which will fail**):

```js
import React from "react"
import { RadioGroup, FormControlLabel, Radio } from "@material-ui/core"
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
})

class ComponentGenerator extends React.Component {

  // ... stuff here ...

  render() {
    const classes = useStyles() // <-- NO! Not a functional component & not
                                // top-level, hooks cannot be used here
    return (
      <RadioGroup
        name="source"
        value={source}
        onChange={this.handleEstablishingChange.bind(this)}
      >
        <FormControlLabel
          value="switching"
          control={<Radio />}
          labelPlacement="start"
          label={"Switching"}
          classes={classes}
        />
        <hr />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="new_source"
          control={<Radio />}
          labelPlacement="start"
          label={"New Service"}
          classes={classes}
        />
      </RadioGroup>
    )
  }
}
```

A solution is to externalize the inner component that uses hooks:

```js
src/components/UI/MyRadio.js

import { FormControlLabel, Radio } from "@material-ui/core"
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
})

const MyRadio = ({ value, label }) => {

  const classes = useStyles() // <-- YES! Functional component & top-level

  return (
    <FormControlLabel
      value={value}
      control={<Radio />}
      labelPlacement="start"
      label={label}
      classes={classes}
    />
  )
}

export default MyRadio
```

and in your component generator:

```js
src/components/ComponentGenerator.js

import React from "react"
import { RadioGroup } from "@material-ui/core"
import MyRadio from "./UI/MyRadio"

class ComponentGenerator extends React.Component {

  // ... stuff here ...

  render() {
    return (
      <RadioGroup
        name="source"
        value={source}
        onChange={this.handleEstablishingChange.bind(this)}
      >
        <MyRadio
          value="switching"
          label={"Switching"}
        />
        <hr />
        <MyRadio
          value="new_source"
          label={"New Service"}
        />
      </RadioGroup>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the great answer. My material UI components are being returned from the render method of a component. When I try to integrate this answer I get "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call". I haven't used hooks before and am having a very difficult time following the documentation as it seems to depend on knowing a number of React-specific terms and concepts already that I'm not familiar enough with. Any tips on how I might integrate this into a FormControlLabel created a Component render method?

Comment: @BenMcCann Hooks come with very strict rules: they can **only** be called at the *top-level* of a *function* component (i.e. not a Class). So if you attempt to declare a hook inside the render function (not top-level) of what is obviously a class-based component (not functional) you're going to have a problem. However, you could declare your custom component separately (as a functional component), import it into your class component, and use it (conditionally or not) in your render method.

Comment: @BenMcCann I've added a section to my answer with an example on how to cope with hooks restrictions by breaking up your code into smaller modules (always a better idea anyway!) - hope this helps

Comment: This is beyond awesome! It helped me solve my problem. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> Problem

After looking at the css material-UI adds on passing `start` in `labelPlacement` prop, it gives property

```
flex-direction: row-reverse;
```

so it is expected that the element starts from the end (horizontally).

---

> Solution

The workaround solution of it is, add a property

```
justifyContent: 'space-between';
```

to the `labelPlacementStart` class.

```
     <FormControlLabel
        value="new_source"
        control={<Radio />}
        labelPlacement="start"
        label={"World"}
        classes={{
          labelPlacementStart: classes.labelPlacementStart
        }}
      />

    const STYLES = theme => createStyles({
      labelPlacementStart: {
         justifyContent: 'space-between'
      }
    })
```

[image]

[Look at this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-platform-03fwm)

Comment: Thanks Siraj. This doesn't quite seem to accomplish what I was aiming for. I was looking for the labels to be on the left and the radio buttons to be on the right with a large space between them. Let me know whether that makes sense or if some other clarification would be useful.

Comment: So, you want the label on the extreme left and the radio button on the extreme right of the container? is that it?

Comment: Yes, that is it

Comment: Then simply override the class and add the property `justify-content: space-between`